# C++ Setter/Getter, cout works, printf fails

Tags: c++, printf, variadic-functions, getter, cout

Does anybody know why C++ fails on the variadic printf function? Is the code fixable? It's just an easy example, but the general case is important to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Float32 {
    public:
        float & operator = (const float &newValue) {
            return value = newValue;
        }
        operator float () const {
            return value;
        }
    protected:
        float value;
};

int main() {
    Float32 value;
    value = 0.5;

    cout << "cout value: " << value << endl; // this works
    printf("something fishy about varargs or something...\n");

    printf("printf value: %f", value); // fails (outputs random garbage value)
}
```

In case this is a compiler bug/issue, I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: 1. Enable compiler warnings. 2. Include expected and actual behaviour in your post. 3. The format specifier %f expects float value, not "Float32" object

Comment: @KamilCuk 2) the comments say whats wrong 3) `value()` doesnt work, only `value.operator float()`

Comment: @lama12345 Yes, I'm sorry, at first I incorrectly read `float operator()` and was confused by it.  @NickyC It comes from my comment, which I edited later and removed that part.

Comment: @Kamil Read questions more thoroughly please!

Comment: I guess I will never ask a C++ question again, only downvoters here. @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the answer

Comment: @lama12345 Don't worry! In long term this question will look better. It is at least useful to explain what's the real difference of formatting output with `printf()` in contrary to the `std::cout`. The `printf()` formatting options still have their advantages over using `std::cout` (e.g. the latter is bad with using internationalized code for various languages).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yea, I don't wanna miss printf, but being able to simply forget the float casting is kinda attracting printf/output bugs and it would be hard to detect in a large code base

Comment: @lama12345 Sure, and that's not easy to understand the different behavior as with using `std::cout` in contrary. Your question is useful and there's nothing missing with it. I am pretty sure others looking for similar problems in future will profit from it.

Comment: @lama12345 The c++ community has pretty high standards regarding research done in prior of asking questions here, and the DV triggers are low resistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In case this is a compiler bug/issue, I am using Visual Studio 2017.

No, there's no compiler bug. Everything works as expected.

> Does anybody know why C++ fails on the variadic printf function?

```
printf("printf value: %f", value);
```

doesn't implicitly call your conversion operator and strictly expect a `float` value, not a `Float32` instance.

It can't do that since the `%f` is resolved at runtime, and there's no way that `printf()` knows your class has a conversion operator at that time.

> Is the code fixable?

You have to do the cast explicitly still:

```
printf("printf value: %f", (float)value);
```

---

As `template<typename T> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream, const T&)` is a template function, it will deduce the best possible conversion at compile time, and this will work in contrary.